# What is a good book on topological groups?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, textbook-recommendation

I am looking for a good book on Topological Groups. I have read Pontryagin myself, and I looked some other in the library but they all seem to go in length into some esoteric topics.

I would love something 250 pages or so long, with good exercises, accessible to a 1st PhD student with background in Algebra, i.e. with an introduction covering necessary background in Functional Analysis.

If possible, I would also like it covering particularly important (in my view) topics:

- emphasize on locally compact groups, but both locally Euclidean and totally disconnected cases;
- [Pontryagin duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality);
- [Kazhdan property T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazhdan%27s_property_(T));
- [Tannaka reconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannaka%E2%80%93Krein_duality#Theorems_of_Tannaka_and_Krein).

Comment: You might want to take a look at Hewitt-Ross (two volumes).

Comment: should be cw...

Comment: 250 pages *and* covering all those topics, while including an "introduction covering necessary background in Functional Analysis"? *Really*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not aware of a book that covers simultaneously Pontryagin duality, property (T) and Tannaka duality. I will refrain from recommending any book on property (T) (guess why?). Apart from Weil's book already mentioned, my favourite ones are:

- for Pontryagin duality: Rudin's "Fourier analysis on groups";
- for functional analytic aspects: Loomis' ``An introduction to abstract harmonic analysis'';
- for representation theory and Tannaka duality (and learning through exercises!): Kirillov's ``Elements of the theory of representations''.
- for group $C^*$-algebras: the second half of Dixmier's $C^*$-algebras''.

Answer (score 8):

How about Weil's classic:  "L'intégration dans les groupes topologiques et ses applications"?  You won't find Kazhdan's Property T nor Tannaka reconstruction, but it treats the other topics deeply and beautifully.  Plus, it's good French practice if the 1st-year PhD student needs the practice.

Answer (score 8):

Try [An Introduction to Topological Groups](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item1123302/) by P. J. Higgins (London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series 15, 1975).

Answer (score 7):

Hewitt & Ross, *Abstract Harmonic Analysis* vol. 1, 1968

but it seems you didn't want 500 pages

Answer (score 4):

For Tannaka duality of compact groups, you can also have a look at Hochschild's book, "The structure of Lie groups"; it also covers a bit of locally compact group theory if I remember well. For everything except Kazhdan, Hewitt & Ross' books are indeed nice (but perhaps a bit too much to digest at once).

Answer (score 3):

I have just read T. Tao's 'Hilbert's Fifth Problem and Related Topics"
and I found it fantastic.

Comment: Does it have anything on Tannaka reconstruction and Pontrjagin duality, as the question mentions?